# Python Dir(**smtn**) in C#

Tags: python, c#

Going from Python as a first programming language I am wondering if there is anything in C# that you can do to get all available methods or parameters in a way like Dir() does in python, where if you didn't know how to use a function or if you were using a foreign library, you would type in Dir(Unknown_Thing) and it would return every method / call you can do on the single thing you placed inside Dir()

Comment: If you use an IDE, you can show all available/applicable methods/properties just with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Oh yea, you are right, just like Visual Studio which always suggests while typing!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything like this. But I also believe that this "output" of information would not be very helpful. It would be much more effective to use an intelligent IDE like Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code.
The "output" of this info, if it existed, would also be quite incomplete until one had added all the NuGet packages that are part of .NET.

**My suggestion:**

A good IDE, brain power and Google research is all it takes to write reasonably good applications.

Comment: This isnt an answer, and should not have been accepted. If your code is running outside your IDE, such as when you deploy it to a secure server, you might only get access to the text logs. An IDE is not an answer to this question. Also, C# has lots of reflection tools in the CLR to inspect objects, so this capability categorically exists, just not as a simple method on every object.

Comment: If I understood the question asked at the beginning correctly, it's about finding out how methods are used in the incredibly large number of API's.
If someone needs a list of all methods with a signature, you can certainly relit it with reflections. But then you would have to set all the references to the libraries.
I think I understood the question correctly and that's why it was accepted as the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really think there's something like that in C# if you wanna know about available functions, just check out the documentation and API preference page of that lib. Also, the visual studio provides IntelliSense, and most decent libraries provide [XML documentation comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/) on their functions and objects